# BIOS detects RAM but Linux is not using all of it

Tags: 20.04, ram, bios, memory-usage

I have 2x 4gb RAM modules installed in slot 1 & 2 on my mobo, with the server running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. It looks like BIOS is seeing both modules:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17
Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000F
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: A1_DIMM0
        Bank Locator: A1_BANK0
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 667 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Corsair
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
        Part Number: CMZ12GX3M3A1600C9
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 667 MT/s

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x000F
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: A1_DIMM1
        Bank Locator: A1_BANK1
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 667 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Corsair
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
        Part Number: CMZ12GX3M3A1600C9
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 667 MT/s
```

But if I run htop it shows 3.8GB total memory.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: What is the output of `lsmem` command?

Comment: It is quite normal.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli RANGE                                  SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE BLOCK
0x0000000000000000-0x00000000dfffffff  3.5G online       yes  0-27
0x0000000100000000-0x000000011fffffff  512M online       yes 32-35

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:       4G
Total offline memory:      0B

Comment: @Pilot6 as in this is a frequent issue, or it is not actually a problem?

Comment: It is not a problem at all. If you have an integrated GPU, up to 2 GB can be used for it. But if you don't have one, this is quite normal.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have a GPU connected through PCI. Thanks

Comment: @ParkerThomas Could you add output of: `uname -a`